# D3js transition mess?

Tags: d3.js, d3.geo

I get stranges artifacts during my reprojection's transition (from top to bottom) :

(1) Starting state snapshot :
[image]

(2) Transitioning (zooming-in) snapshot:
[image]

(3) Final state snapshot:
[image]

The [live demo](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/2_zoom/index.html) is there. No error messages in the console. Both initial and final states are perfect. I have no clue. **Any experience with such transition / reprojection display bugs ?**

Comment: Interestingly, only path projected via `datum()` seems affected.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045826/how-to-do-smooth-transition-for-map-reprojection-in-d3-js)? A straightforward transition won't work in most cases.

Comment: 1. Bug still here after migration to `data()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, it doesn't seems to be reprojection related, the common case is just making scale transition to zoom in & out together with a translation for recentering the view. All of these synchronously on equirectangular.

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem -- you're *setting* the projection attributes and then *transitioning* the `d` attributes of the paths. This approach suffers from the exact problem that Mike describes in his answer.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: ok, thanks, I return to dig on this.