# Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute -- During a d3 Projection Transition -- Infinity & NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, map-projections

I am working on a transition between Orthogonal and Mercator projections on an interactive map (zoom + drag) of the world. I based my attempt off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050599/4589331) by @mbostock. My transition works well but the console returns this:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d= "M399.97994119370463,631.2543931983346L401.90905516286807,634.6157013775801L402.49382423943246,639.8924592362391L397.1999166487309,.......,**InfinityL492,InfinityL298.23496934976544,InfinityZ**"

also

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M407.5277462873383,448.4656515493841L407.3237573717514,448.5198670656254L408.0599991645186,448.54332648718287L408.0215749188842,448.4385574971469ZM410.40575858016456,448.5990104765492L410.8017911794915,448.571665201377L411.4470970198755...,NaNL415,NaNL415,**NaNZM415,NaNL415,NaNL415,NaNZM415,NaNL415**,449.0295187376797L415,449.0295187376797L414.9999381778805,449.02952802059315L415,449.02952802059315L414.41200773961845,.."

I am using topoJson from a Natural Earth shapefile and I only receive one of these path errors for each time the tween function is returned. I believe this means that only one path element that is having this problem.

Here are my transition methods that I have within a projection class:

```js
animation(timeout, newProjection) {
  let self = this;
  let projection = this.interpolatedProjection(this.prjFnc, newProjection);
  let path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
  this.svg.transition()
    .duration(timeout / 2)
    .tween('projection', function() {
      return function(_) {
        self.alpha(_);
        self.svg.selectAll('path').attr('d', path);
      };
    });
}
interpolatedProjection(a, b) {
  let self = this;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.α = null;
  function raw(λ, φ) {
    let pa = self.a([λ *= 180 / Math.PI, φ *= 180 / Math.PI]), pb = self.b([λ, φ]);
    return [(1 - self.α) * pa[0] + self.α * pb[0], (self.α - 1) * pa[1] - self.α * pb[1]];
  }
  this.intProjection = d3.geo.projection(raw).scale(1);
  this.center = this.intProjection.center;
  this.translate = this.intProjection.translate;
  delete this.intProjection.scale;
  delete this.intProjection.translate;
  delete this.intProjection.center;
  return this.alpha(0.1);
}
alpha(_) {
  if(!arguments.length) {
    return this.α;
  }
  this.α = +_;
  let ca = this.a.center(),
      cb = this.b.center(),
      ta = this.a.translate(),
      tb = this.b.translate();

  this.center(
    [(1 - this.α) * ca[0] + this.α * cb[0],
    (1 - this.α) * ca[1] + this.α * cb[1]]
  );
  this.translate(
    [Math.round((1 - this.α) * ta[0] + this.α * tb[0]),
    Math.round((1 - this.α) * ta[1] + this.α * tb[1])]
  );
  return this.intProjection;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're sure it's not the occurences of `infinity` in your paths that is the issue, it seems something is failing during calculation ?

Comment: @adeneo I definitely agree. I am thinking that something is going wrong in the "raw" function. But I am unsure of how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The infinity errors were caused by paths attempting be drawn outside of the svg. I was able to remove these errors by adding a Clip Extent to the interpolated projection.

```
interpolatedProjection(a, b) {
  let self = this;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.α = null;
  function raw(λ, φ) {
    let pa = self.a([λ *= 180 / Math.PI, φ *= 180 / Math.PI]), pb = self.b([λ, φ]);
    return [(1 - self.α) * pa[0] + self.α * pb[0], (self.α - 1) * pa[1] - self.α * pb[1]];
  }
  this.intProjection = d3.geo.projection(raw).scale(1)

    .clipExtent(this.extent); // this addition

  this.center = this.intProjection.center;
  this.translate = this.intProjection.translate;
  delete this.intProjection.scale;
  delete this.intProjection.translate;
  delete this.intProjection.center;
  return this.alpha(0.1);
}
```

I was also was receiving a NaN error in the d attribute in which I was able to remove by not letting the tween index reach a value of 1.

```
animation(timeout, newProjection) {
  let self = this;
  let projection = this.interpolatedProjection(this.prjFnc, newProjection);
  let path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
  this.svg.transition()
    .duration(timeout)
    .tween('projection', function() {
      return function(_) {

        if (_ === 1) { return; } // This addition

        self.alpha(_);
        self.paths.attr('d', path);
      };
    });
}
```