# Interpolation Method for Projection Transition in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, interpolation, projection

I am attempting to toggle between two animations while having them be interactive (drag/zoom) - orthographic and equirectangular. I would be grateful if anyone could help shed some light on the issues I'm about to explain. Without explanation, this math is a little over my head.

My interpolation method is based off of this extremely helpful answer: [How to do smooth transition for map reprojection in d3 js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045826/how-to-do-smooth-transition-for-map-reprojection-in-d3-js/17050599#17050599)

I've created two similar examples on jsfiddle - one that starts out with an orthographic projection without being interpolated and another that is. On line 24 you can easily switch between the interpolated projection and the normal orthographic.

These are identical except for the projection getting applied (line 24/25):

- Normal orthographic (how the interpolated should look): http://jsfiddle.net/jsv5ap3f/3/
- The interpolated attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/jsv5ap3f/2/

You'll notice they visually look quite different, which brings me to my questions:

1. I believe the way to handle the toggle is to create 2 interpolating projections (as seen in jsfiddle). 1 going from orthographic to equirectangular (`ortho2Equi`), then another doing the opposite. Then apply them to the `path` when appropriate (`equi2ortho`). Or would there be a better more efficient way?
2. You'll notice the interpolated method causes the globe to lose most of its styling - mainly centering, the inner blue sphere, and clipping. The loss of `clipAngle()` seems the be the main culprit in the interpolated orthographic projection. Is there anyway to keep the `transform()`, `clipAngle()`, `rotate()` and `scale()` as they are on the vanilla orthographic? I suspect they'll need to be "hard coded" in each of the interpolation methods?
3. What is the purpose of the 3 `delete`s at the bottom of the interpolation method?

Thank you!

Comment: The first link doesn't do anything when you click on the red button... http://jsfiddle.net/jsv5ap3f/3/

Comment: Correct. The first example is to only show how the globe should look. It's not interpolated.